# wintun:ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER on registering ring buffers

Tags: c++, c, windows, tun, wintun

I am currently trying to get the `wintun` driver to work with my program for simple tunneling (see: https://www.wintun.net/ ).

I successfully find and open the network device, but when it comes to registering the buffer, I get the result `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` (87). Like I said, opening works just fine and registering is done with `SYSTEM` privileges (if this is not done, I get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5)).

First attempt was to `malloc` the ring buffers, but after that did not work I looked at how OpenVPN does it (yes, it added wintun support) and they seem to do with with `CreateFileMapping`.

First of all, here is my struct:

```
typedef struct _TUN_RING {
    volatile ULONG Head;
    volatile ULONG Tail;
    volatile LONG Alertable;
    UCHAR Data[(1024 * 1024) + 0x10000];
} TUN_RING;
```

which is according to the docs (https://git.zx2c4.com/wintun/about/ section "Ring Layout). Also its the same as OpenVPN does.

After that I create the file mapping

```
send_ring_handle_ = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
                                            nullptr,
                                            PAGE_READWRITE,
                                            0,
                                            sizeof(TUN_RING),
                                            nullptr);
recv_ring_handle_ = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
                                            nullptr,
                                            PAGE_READWRITE,
                                            0,
                                            sizeof(TUN_RING),
                                            nullptr);
```

Then I create the mappings:

```
send_ring_ = (TUN_RING *)MapViewOfFile(send_ring_handle_,
                                         FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
                                         0,
                                         0,
                                         sizeof(TUN_RING));
recv_ring_ = (TUN_RING *)MapViewOfFile(recv_ring_handle_,
                                         FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
                                         0,
                                         0,
                                         sizeof(TUN_RING));
```

and finally (after impersonating the system user) trying to register it with `DeviceIoControl`:

```
    TUN_REGISTER_RINGS reg_rings;
    memset(&reg_rings, 0, sizeof(TUN_REGISTER_RINGS));
    reg_rings.Send.RingSize = sizeof(TUN_RING);
    reg_rings.Send.Ring = send_ring_;
    reg_rings.Send.TailMoved = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
    reg_rings.Receive.RingSize = sizeof(TUN_RING);
    reg_rings.Receive.Ring = recv_ring_;
    reg_rings.Receive.TailMoved = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0);

    DWORD len;
    if (!DeviceIoControl(tun_fd_,
                            TUN_IOCTL_REGISTER_RINGS,
                            &reg_rings,
                            sizeof(reg_rings),
                            nullptr,
                            0,
                            &len,
                            nullptr))
    {
        printf("Could not register ring buffers (%d).", ::GetLastError());
        return false;
    }
```

Can anybody point me to where I am wrong? Like I said, with `malloc` instead of the file mapping the same error arieses.

I have written a complete example by now using `malloc`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winioctl.h>
#include <IPHlpApi.h>
#include <ndisguid.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <securitybaseapi.h>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct _TUN_PACKET_PROTO {
    ULONG Size;
    UCHAR Data[]; // max packet size as defined by the driver.
} TUN_PACKET_PROTO;

typedef struct _TUN_RING_PROTO {
    volatile ULONG Head;
    volatile ULONG Tail;
    volatile LONG Alertable;
    UCHAR Data[];
} TUN_RING_PROTO;


#define TUN_IOCTL_REGISTER_RINGS CTL_CODE(51820U, 0x970U, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_DATA | FILE_WRITE_DATA)
#define TUN_IOCTL_FORCE_CLOSE_HANDLES CTL_CODE(51820U, 0x971U, METHOD_NEITHER, FILE_READ_DATA | FILE_WRITE_DATA)

#define WINTUN_RING_CAPACITY        0x800000
#define WINTUN_RING_TRAILING_BYTES  0x10000
#define WINTUN_MAX_PACKET_SIZE      0xffff
#define WINTUN_PACKET_ALIGN         4

/* Memory alignment of packets and rings */
#define TUN_ALIGNMENT sizeof(ULONG)
#define TUN_ALIGN(Size) (((ULONG)(Size) + ((ULONG)TUN_ALIGNMENT - 1)) & ~((ULONG)TUN_ALIGNMENT - 1))
#define TUN_IS_ALIGNED(Size) (!((ULONG)(Size) & ((ULONG)TUN_ALIGNMENT - 1)))
/* Maximum IP packet size */
#define TUN_MAX_IP_PACKET_SIZE 0xFFFF
/* Maximum packet size */
#define TUN_MAX_PACKET_SIZE TUN_ALIGN(sizeof(TUN_PACKET_PROTO) + TUN_MAX_IP_PACKET_SIZE)
/* Minimum ring capacity. */
#define TUN_MIN_RING_CAPACITY 0x20000 /* 128kiB */
/* Maximum ring capacity. */
#define TUN_MAX_RING_CAPACITY 0x4000000 /* 64MiB */
/* Calculates ring capacity */
#define TUN_RING_CAPACITY(Size) ((Size) - sizeof(TUN_RING_PROTO) - (TUN_MAX_PACKET_SIZE - TUN_ALIGNMENT))
/* Calculates ring offset modulo capacity */
#define TUN_RING_WRAP(Value, Capacity) ((Value) & (Capacity - 1))

#define IS_POW2(x) ((x) && !((x) & ((x)-1)))



typedef struct _TUN_RING {
    volatile ULONG Head;
    volatile ULONG Tail;
    volatile LONG Alertable;
    UCHAR Data[WINTUN_RING_CAPACITY + (TUN_MAX_PACKET_SIZE-TUN_ALIGNMENT)];
} TUN_RING;

typedef struct _TUN_PACKET {
    ULONG Size;
    UCHAR Data[WINTUN_MAX_PACKET_SIZE]; // max packet size as defined by the driver.
} TUN_PACKET;

typedef struct _TUN_REGISTER_RINGS {
    struct {
        ULONG RingSize;
        TUN_RING *Ring;
        HANDLE TailMoved;
    } Send, Receive;
} TUN_REGISTER_RINGS;
#pragma pack(pop)

class regkey_t
{
public:
    regkey_t(void);
    regkey_t(HKEY handle);
    ~regkey_t(void);

    void attach(HKEY handle);
    void release(void);

    HKEY detach(void);
    operator HKEY (void) const;
    HKEY &get(void);
    HKEY *operator &(void);

private:
    regkey_t(const regkey_t &);
    regkey_t &operator = (const regkey_t &);

    HKEY handle_;
};

regkey_t::regkey_t():
    handle_(0)
{
}

regkey_t::regkey_t(HKEY handle):
    handle_(handle)
{
}

regkey_t::~regkey_t(void)
{
    release();
}

void regkey_t::attach(HKEY handle)
{
    release();
    handle_ = handle;
}

void regkey_t::release(void)
{
    if (handle_)
    {
        const LONG res (::RegCloseKey(handle_));
        if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("Couldn't close a reg handle (%lu).\n", res);
        }

        handle_ = 0;
    }
}

HKEY regkey_t::detach(void)
{
    const HKEY result (handle_);
    handle_ = 0;
    return result;
}

HKEY &regkey_t::get(void)
{
    return handle_;
}

HKEY *regkey_t::operator &(void)
{
    return &handle_;
}

regkey_t::operator HKEY(void) const
{
    return handle_;
}

bool impersonate_as_system()
{
    HANDLE thread_token, process_snapshot, winlogon_process, winlogon_token, duplicated_token;
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    BOOL ret;
    DWORD pid = 0;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES privileges;

    ::memset(&entry, 0, sizeof(entry));
    ::memset(&privileges, 0, sizeof(privileges));

    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    privileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    privileges.Privileges->Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &privileges.Privileges[0].Luid))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!ImpersonateSelf(SecurityImpersonation))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, FALSE, &thread_token))
    {
        RevertToSelf();
        return false;
    }
    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(thread_token, FALSE, &privileges, sizeof(privileges), NULL, NULL))
    {
        CloseHandle(thread_token);
        RevertToSelf();
        return false;
    }
    CloseHandle(thread_token);

    process_snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (process_snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        RevertToSelf();
        return false;
    }
    for (ret = Process32First(process_snapshot, &entry); ret; ret = Process32Next(process_snapshot, &entry))
    {
        if (::strcmp(entry.szExeFile, "winlogon.exe") == 0)
        {
            pid = entry.th32ProcessID;
            break;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(process_snapshot);
    if (!pid)
    {
        RevertToSelf();
        return false;
    }

    winlogon_process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
    if (!winlogon_process)
    {
        RevertToSelf();
        return false;
    }

    if (!OpenProcessToken(winlogon_process, TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &winlogon_token))
    {
        CloseHandle(winlogon_process);
        RevertToSelf();
        return false;
    }
    CloseHandle(winlogon_process);

    if (!DuplicateToken(winlogon_token, SecurityImpersonation, &duplicated_token))
    {
        CloseHandle(winlogon_token);
        RevertToSelf();
        return false;
    }
    CloseHandle(winlogon_token);

    if (!SetThreadToken(NULL, duplicated_token))
    {
        CloseHandle(duplicated_token);
        RevertToSelf();
        return false;
    }
    CloseHandle(duplicated_token);

    return true;
}

std::string get_instance_id(uint32_t device_index)
{
    const std::string key_name("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Class\\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}");

    std::string device_id("");

    regkey_t adapters;
    DWORD ret = ::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key_name.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ, &adapters);
    if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Could not open registry key %s (%d).\n", key_name.c_str(), ret);

        return device_id;
    }

    DWORD sub_keys(0);
    ret = ::RegQueryInfoKey(adapters, NULL, NULL, NULL, &sub_keys, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Could not get info from %s (%d).\n", key_name.c_str(), ret);
        return device_id;
    }

    if (sub_keys <= 0)
    {
        printf("Wrong registry key %s.\n", key_name.c_str());
        return device_id;
    }

    if (device_index >= sub_keys)
    {
        return device_id;
    }

    uint32_t index(0);
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < sub_keys; i++)
    {
        const uint32_t max_key_length = 255;
        TCHAR key[max_key_length];
        DWORD keylen(max_key_length);

        // Get the adapter name
        ret = ::RegEnumKeyEx(adapters, i, key, &keylen, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Append it to NETWORK_ADAPTERS and open it
        regkey_t device;
        const std::string new_key(key_name + "\\" + std::string(key));

        ret = ::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, new_key.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ, &device);
        if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            continue;
        }

        TCHAR data[256];
        DWORD len(sizeof(data));
        ret = ::RegQueryValueEx(device, "ComponentId", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)data, &len);
        if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            continue;
        }

        std::string device_name("wintun");
        if (::_tcsnccmp(data, device_name.c_str(), sizeof(TCHAR) * device_name.length()) == 0)
        {
            if (device_index != index)
            {
                index++;
                continue;
            }

            DWORD type;
            len = sizeof(data);

            ret = ::RegQueryValueEx(device, "DeviceInstanceID", NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)data, &len);
            if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                printf("Could not get info from %s (%d).\n", key_name.c_str(), ret);

            }

            device_id = data;
            break;
        }
    }

    return device_id;
}

bool open_tun_device()
{
    HANDLE tun_fd_ = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    std::string device_id;
    uint32_t device_index;
    {
        TCHAR *interface_list = nullptr;
        for (device_index = 0; device_index < 256; ++device_index)
        {
            device_id = get_instance_id(device_index);
            if (device_id.empty())
            {
                continue;
            }

            CONFIGRET status = CR_SUCCESS;

            // This loop is recommended as "robust code" by MSDN. See the Remarks of CM_Get_Device_Interface_list.
            do
            {
                DWORD required_chars(0);
                if ((status = ::CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Size(&required_chars,
                                                        (LPGUID)&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET,
                                                        (char *)device_id.c_str(),
                                                        CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT)) != CR_SUCCESS || !required_chars)
                {
                    break;
                }

                assert(required_chars > 0);
                interface_list = (TCHAR *)::malloc(sizeof(TCHAR) * required_chars);

                status = ::CM_Get_Device_Interface_List((LPGUID)&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET,
                                                                  (char *)device_id.c_str(),
                                                                  interface_list,
                                                                  required_chars,
                                                                  CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);

                if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
                {
                    break;
                }

                ::free(interface_list);
                interface_list = nullptr;
            } while(status == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);

            if (interface_list)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!interface_list)
        {
            printf("Could not find wintun interface.\n");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            tun_fd_ = ::CreateFile(interface_list,
                                   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                   FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                                   nullptr,
                                   OPEN_EXISTING, 0, nullptr);
        }


        ::free(interface_list);
    }

    if (!tun_fd_ || tun_fd_ == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Could not open wintun device.\n");
        return false;
    }

    printf("Opened wintun device.\n");
    ::Sleep(1000);

    TUN_RING * send_ring_ = (TUN_RING *)::malloc(sizeof(TUN_RING));
    TUN_RING * recv_ring_ = (TUN_RING *)::malloc(sizeof(TUN_RING));

    if (!recv_ring_ || !send_ring_)
    {
        printf("Could not malloc.\n");
        return false;
    }

    ::memset(send_ring_, 0, sizeof(*send_ring_));
    ::memset(recv_ring_, 0, sizeof(*recv_ring_));

    recv_ring_->Alertable = TRUE;
    recv_ring_->Head = 0;
    recv_ring_->Tail = 0;
    send_ring_->Alertable = TRUE;
    send_ring_->Head = 0;
    send_ring_->Tail = 0;

    HANDLE send_event = ::CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    HANDLE recv_event = ::CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    // register the rings
    if (impersonate_as_system())
    {
        TUN_REGISTER_RINGS reg_rings;
        ::memset(&reg_rings, 0, sizeof(TUN_REGISTER_RINGS));
        reg_rings.Send.RingSize = sizeof(TUN_RING);
        reg_rings.Send.Ring = send_ring_;
        reg_rings.Send.TailMoved = send_event;
        reg_rings.Receive.RingSize = sizeof(TUN_RING);
        reg_rings.Receive.Ring = recv_ring_;
        reg_rings.Receive.TailMoved = recv_event;


        int send_capacity = TUN_RING_CAPACITY(reg_rings.Send.RingSize);

        if ((send_capacity < TUN_MIN_RING_CAPACITY || send_capacity > TUN_MAX_RING_CAPACITY ||
             !IS_POW2(send_capacity) || !reg_rings.Send.TailMoved || !reg_rings.Send.Ring))
        {
            printf("Fuck this shit I am out...\n");
        }


        DWORD len;

        DWORD fuckyou = 0;
        if (!::DeviceIoControl(tun_fd_, TUN_IOCTL_FORCE_CLOSE_HANDLES,
                               &fuckyou, sizeof(fuckyou), nullptr, 0, &len, nullptr))
        {
            printf("Error releasing handles (%d).\n", ::GetLastError());
        }


        if (!::DeviceIoControl(tun_fd_,
                                TUN_IOCTL_REGISTER_RINGS,
                                &reg_rings,
                                sizeof(reg_rings),
                                nullptr,
                                0,
                                &len,
                                nullptr))
        {
            printf("Could not register ring buffers (%d).\n", ::GetLastError());
            ::Sleep(10000);
            RevertToSelf();
            return false;
        }
        ::Sleep(10000);
        RevertToSelf();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Could not elevate to SYSTEM\n");
        return false;
    }



    return true;
}

int main()
{
    if (!open_tun_device())
    {
        printf("Experiment failed.\n");
    }

    printf("Size TUNRING: %d (%d)\n", sizeof(TUN_RING),  0x800000 + 0x010000 + 0x0C);
    printf("Capacity: %d\n", TUN_RING_CAPACITY(sizeof(TUN_RING)));
    if (!IS_POW2(TUN_RING_CAPACITY(sizeof(TUN_RING))))
    {
        printf("Shit gone wrong...\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please make sure to **RUN THIS ELEVATED** or you will get error 5 `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: When creating the file handle, openvpn sets the attributes for `CreateFile()` as: `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM|FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`. Have you tried this? Ref: https://build.openvpn.net/doxygen/tun_8c_source.html#l06303

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Tried it right now and incorporated it in my sample. Sadly: same reuslt

Comment: Note that in the aforementioned reference, sharemode is also set to 0, i.e. none.

Comment: tried only to add the flags, after that didnt work I took the call of openvpn 1:1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of trial and error I have translated the whole setup routine from the WireGuard Go code (see here: https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-go ) to C++, which seems to make it work. It accepts the rings now just as in the first post and the device is shown as connected afterwards...

They are doing some registry tweaks after installing the device (see https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-go/blob/4369db522b3fd7adc28a2a82b89315a6f3edbcc4/tun/wintun/wintun_windows.go#L207 ) which I think takes the cake. Thanks for everyone helping in finding this.

Comment: Great! Congrats and kudos. +1 for the info.

Comment: @Nidhoegger possbile to share the c++ code?

Answer (score 1):

I can see a difference in your code when registering rings.

You are doing:

```
reg_rings.Send.RingSize = sizeof(TUN_RING);
reg_rings.Receive.RingSize = sizeof(TUN_RING);
```

While the docs says:

> Send.RingSize, Receive.RingSize: Sizes of the rings (sizeof(TUN_RING) + capacity + 0x10000, as above)

Your ring is `sizeof(TUN_RING) + UCHAR[(1024 * 1024) + 0x10000]`

I guess it can't accept a ring that has no data space?

Sorry, I see your TUN_RING includes de data...

May be the events aren't good:

> If an event is created from a service or a thread that is impersonating a different user, you can either apply a security descriptor to the event when you create it, or change the default security descriptor for the creating process by changing its default DACL

```
reg_rings.Send.TailMoved = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
reg_rings.Receive.TailMoved = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
```

You seem to be using the default DACL.

There may be aligning problems. If `malloc` isn't returning an aligned address for your buffer (as may be in `debug` mode, because there are memory management bytes) your `Data` member for the packet could be not aligned.

You can check the alignment against the address:

```
template <unsigned int alignment>
struct IsAligned
{
    static_assert((alignment & (alignment - 1)) == 0, "Alignment must be a power of 2");

    static inline bool Value(const void * ptr)
    {
        return (((uintptr_t)ptr) & (alignment - 1)) == 0;
    }
};

std::cout << IsAligned<32>::Value(ptr + i) << std::endl;
```

Giving the first packet address `&(TUN_RING.Data[0])` (I guess.)

As said in your comment, it is the case, it is unaligned.
You can try two things.

First reserve memory with [aligned_alloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc) which will give you an aligned buffer for `TUN_RING`.

Second, if `TUN_RING` is already aligned and the `packet` alignment is the problem, then you should give the correct offset to the head and tail:

```
recv_ring_->Head = 0; // <- aligned byte offset
recv_ring_->Tail = 0;
send_ring_->Head = 0;
send_ring_->Tail = 0;
```

Remember:

> Head: Byte offset of the first packet in the ring. Its value must be a multiple of 4 and less than ring capacity.
>
> Tail: Byte offset of the start of free space in the ring. Its value must be multiple of 4 and less than ring capacity.

The byte offset must be a multiple of 4.

You have to increment those skipped bytes to the buffer size. For that you may need to allocate extra space that won't be used, but I think it won't be too much.

In a second view to events, in the docs it says event has to be `auto-reset`:

> Send.TailMoved: A handle to an *auto-reset* event created by the client that Wintun signals after it moves the Tail member of the send ring.
>
> Receive.TailMoved: A handle to an *auto-reset* event created by the client that the client will signal when it changes Receive.Ring->Tail and Receive.Ring->Alertable is non-zero.

In your example, the event is `auto-reset`:

```
HANDLE send_event = ::CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
HANDLE recv_event = ::CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
```

but in the code you show (at top of question) isn't:

```
reg_rings.Send.TailMoved = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
reg_rings.Receive.TailMoved = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
```

I don't know if the parameter checking goes so far as to verify event `auto-reset` setting (not even if that's possible.) Moreover, the [openvpn](https://build.openvpn.net/doxygen/win32_8c_source.html#l00227) code creates them non `auto-reset` (although may be there is some code around to signal them before registering.)

Comment: Tried that already with the events unfortunatley :/

Comment: Just now again tried that to create an all access DACL and assign the attributes in the event creation without any success.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. IsAligned in fact returns false. Is there a way to make that work?

Comment: The answer does not really solve my issue, but I awarded the bounty anyways for the effort that has been put into it! Thank you!

Comment: @Nidhoegger Wow! Thank you very much. I'll continue investigating anyway, I can't stop when I don't understand why something that should work doesn't. :-)

Comment: Same goes with me. I even translated every single line of wireguards go code now to install the driver with my own code and not via the device manager, in case they do some weird registry magic there... it installs, it sets every value they do... nothing.

Comment: Okay, I got this stuff working... even though I dunno how... I translated the whole wireguard go code that goes with TUN stuff and now it works, it includes the whole setupAPI thing and some registry tweaks they do and now the driver accepts the rings.

Answer (score -1):

For me the fix to get rid off ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (87) was to switch from `x86` to `x64` architecture in Visual Studio

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is the alignment of the structs. You align your structs to 1 byte [#pragma pack(push, 1)] while the wintun driver does 8(/ZP8 in the solution). This will result in differing struct sizes and thus the size checks will fall through. Furthermore I would like to recommend that you use VirtualAlloc or the Mapping instead of malloc.

Comment: We tried that and it is not the cause of the issue.

Comment: I tried the malloc version and it worked for me(while wireguard gui tool had a connection stablished), so perhaps something else was wrong in the code when you tried it but it was absolutely a cause.

Comment: https://mega.nz/file/Tl4ghQBY#N9YnJQXe_LNRKiV5lklehNpOr8U3hDDpRmn1wzddLt0

so here is the project i made which definitely works, provided the driver is loaded. please let me know if you wish to see a video of it working!